# Notifying posters of comments restricted?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, comments

I've noticed that comments I make are being stripped of the "@name" part. For example, my comment [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106837/update-manager-always-says-it-is-outdated), "*@yossile, the OP has mentioned **Google Chrome beta** and there is (or was) a problem regarding it described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105102/does-someone-know-why-the-chromium-daily-package-isnt-build-anymore). So, as you suggest, disabling the relevant repository should help.*" displays **without** the "@yossile" bit.

Is it possible to know the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first comment for any post is usually about the post itself and hence adding the @ to notify the post author is redundant and the system has probably removed it. If you were using @ to notify someone else, I am guessing the system would just leave it there.

Answer (score 2):

If you are the first to comment on a question/answer, then the system assumes you are referring to the OP themselves and hence strips the *@yossile*.

You would normally only need to use *@yossile* where there are multiple commentators and you want to respond directly to them.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you are posting an comment under a post and want to refer the user that posted it there is no need ping his name, a notification will be sent to him anyways.

Under a question, the user that posted the question gets notification of all the comments, under an answer the same thing, its not just the first comment, all comments made under a post will send a notification to the user that created the post, either a question or an answer.

There is no need to ping the user that created the post if you are commenting in the post he created.

That should only be necessary to refer another user other than the user that made the post. The system removes it automatically because you can ping max 2 users in a comment and adding the user that created the post is useless, so it is removed.

[image]